# Putting a movieclip as child for another movieclip

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

So I have the `MovieClip` `mc1` which added to the stage (`addChild`) is put on top of all the layers. I actually need another movieclip to be on top of all the scene so I've created an empty movieclip with the instance name `fbp`, that is set on the appropriate layer, in which I want to put my mc1 movieclip. How can I get that `fbp` movieclip and then add mc1 as child?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fbp.addChild(mc1)`. However, you might need to make a Sprite instead of MovieClip for `fbp`. Not sure if it works for movieclips.

Comment: Simple as that!  I was trying to use getChildbyName and other stuff. Thank you!:)

Comment: You're welcome :) This method (commonly called a container var(`fbp` here)) is especially useful for adding multiple child vars to it. Then you can control *all* of the child vars by simply applying stuff to the container/parent var. :D